# How to make proxy of a rig?

Tags: rigging

I am following the steps on the website https://cloud.blender.org and here is what it says.

1. Put your 3D cursor in the Origin of your scene. Choose File > Link and browse the character file
2. Go to the Collections and select CH-Vincent.high. Make sure "Instance Collections" is enabled. Press Enter.
3. The Collection should appear instanced in the Viewport. Select it.
4. Choose Object > Relations > Make Proxy...
5. In the list, select RIG-Vincent. If the model is too heavy, enable Simplify in the Render Settings.
6. Pose the proxy armature to your liking and enjoy!

I am stuck on step 4. Where do I find Object > Relations > Make Proxy...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the header menu. If you still can't find it, please show a screenshot of your 3D view.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it worked